# First setup of Git - how to connect?

Tags: git, visual-studio, windows-7, redhat, git-extensions

I have a RedHat server on which I have installed Git, additional with `git init` in my `/home/rko` I have created my repo at `/home/rko/.git`.

That's it, but how to connect to this repo? I tried different tools with remote repo functions but can't connect on any of them.

I'm using Windows 7 with Visual Studio, I tried e.g. `GitExtentions` and `SmartGit`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to turn your whole home directory into a repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this chapter of git-scm](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).

In brief:

- create a unix user called `git`
- add SSH keys to their `authorized_keys` file
- run `git init --bare` (in a directory called `/some/path/yourproject.git/`) to create a repository without a working tree on the server
- initialise the repository locally for one of the clients, `git init`
- add the remote: `git remote add origin git@gitserver:/some/path/yourproject.git`
- push it to the server: `git push origin master`